# Import .txt file Western (Windows-1252) with "£" as field delimiter and date field conversion to mysql table with php

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I'm trying to import a .txt file from a local folder where the delimiter is "£" to a mySQL table but it keeps sending it all to the first field.

I'm using this code:

```
$sql = ("LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'C:/xampp/htdocs/test/test.txt' 
            INTO TABLE tabletxt 
            FIELDS TERMINATED BY '£'
            LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' 
            IGNORE 1 LINES (name, country, date);");
if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
     echo "New record created successfully";
}               
else {
     echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}
```

Also I need to convert the date field to date, here is one line of example from the file `Luke£France£29.01.2016`

Thank you

Comment: Encoding differences?

Comment: The table is in utf8_unicode_ci and the code has <head>
 <meta charset= "UTF-8">
</head>

Comment: @iliketurtles What encoding is the txt file in?

Comment: The txt file is in Western (Windows-1252)